# Postgres creates tables that are SELECTed INTO even if the rule has no rows to act on

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, temp-tables, rule

I've created an ON DELETE rule on a view that SELECTs OLD into a temporary table and then calls a function that performs actions using the values of OLD. The rule deletes the temporary table before running the SELECT INTO TEMPORARY TABLE in case the rule is called more than once during a session by performing a SELECT dropTempTable(). This all works fine except when there is nothing to delete e.g. running the following query when there are no records with a name of 'John Doe':

```
DELETE FROM myview WHERE name = 'John Doe';
```

In this case the temporary table is created by the planner in preparation for it being used even though it won't be, but my dropTempTable() statement is never called so the second time I perform a DELETE on my view, it fails because the temporary table already exists. Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem will be greatly appreciated. I realise that this example could be better solved using a Trigger but I've simplified it for the purposes of this post and a Trigger won't work for my particular problem.

My View:

```
CREATE VIEW myview 
AS SELECT * FROM mytable
```

My Rule:

```
CREATE RULE myview_delete
AS ON DELETE TO myview
DO INSTEAD (
     SELECT dropTempTable();
     SELECT OLD INTO TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable;
     SELECT myDeleteFunction();
);
```

My Drop Table Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dropTempTable()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTempTable;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "*a trigger won't work for my particular problem*". Why?

Comment: I would **never** drop and create tables inside a rule. Never. IMO the rewrite rule would not be too difficult in this case; basically a `delete from temptable where exist (select * from realtable where keyfield = temptable.keyfield and realtable.keyfield = OLD.keyfield);` BTW: do you realise that this rule is invoked per statement?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I can't use a trigger because I have several legacy clients currently communicating with Postgres and it will be a while before I can replace them. Meanwhile, we're migrating to a new backend so in order to continue supporting the legacy clients, I've written functions using Postgres' built in languages that bridge Postgres and the new backend. In some cases no data actually gets written to the Postgres tables that a trigger would apply to. Of course I've got SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE rules that support this. I know this sounds messy, but I had few options and it works

Comment: One of the reasons I have to drop the tables from my rule manually is because I couldn't figure out a way create a temporary table from within a rule with an ON COMMIT DROP statement that I could then INSERT OLD INTO within the rule. As per the Postgres docs, I can only use SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE and NOTIFY statements inside a rule.
It's not obvious to me how the rewrite rule example you've given enables me to pass OLD to myFunction but if it does, I'd be very interested in more information about doing this.

Comment: Yes, I do realize Rules are per statement, whereas a trigger can also be per row, and this has also caused me problems but so far, I've been able to work through those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving my call to the dropTempTable function out of the DELETE rule and into the SELECT rule with the addition of an EXCEPTION statement so it looks like:

My Drop Table Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dropTempTable()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTempTable;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works.